# Matlab choose linear direct sparse solver

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, solver, suitesparse

I need to solve a sparse linear system in Matalab using the QR solver of SuiteSparse. How can I choose it? I know that, depending on the matrix structure, the QR solver is used when calling the "\" operator. But I haven't find any way to directly use it. Is there any documentation?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

From Matlab manual, the least squares approximate solution to A*x = b can be found as:

```
      R = qr(A);
      x = R\(R'\(A'*b));
      r = b - A*x;
      e = R\(R'\(A'*r));
      x = x + e;
```